# How to feed Nifti Images in 3d CNN for classification?

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, medical-imaging, 3d-convolution

I have 142 Nifti CT images of the brain, I converted them from Dicom. Every NIfti file has the dimension of 512×512×40. My plan is to work with 3d Conv Neural Network for multi-class classification. How should I feed Nifti images in a 3d CNN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to use TensorFlow, you might consider the folowing steps:

- Load your dataset using tf.data

> ```
> train_loader = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
> validation_loader = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_val, y_val))
> ```

- Apply your preprocessing steps

  ```
   train_dataset = (
   train_loader.shuffle(len(x_train))
   .map(train_preprocessing)
   .batch(1)
   .prefetch(2))

  validation_dataset = (
       validation_loader.shuffle(len(x_val))
       .map(validation_preprocessing)
       .batch(1)
       .prefetch(2)
   )
  ```

Build your 3D CNN model:

```
def 3D_model(width= 512, height= 512, depth=40):
 
    inputs = keras.Input((width, height, depth, 1))

    x = layers.Conv3D(filters=84, kernel_size=3, activation="relu")(inputs)
    x = layers.MaxPool3D(pool_size=2,padding="same")(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

    x = layers.Conv3D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu")(x)
    x = layers.MaxPool3D(pool_size=2,padding="same")(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    outputs = layers.Dense(units=n_classes, activation="softmax")(x)
    model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
    return model
model = get_model(width=512, height=512, depth=40)
```

- Train your model:

> ```
> 3D_model.compile(..)
> 3D_model.fit(
>     train_dataset,
>     validation_data=validation_dataset,
>     epochs=epochs,
>     shuffle=True)
> ```

You can also refer to this [example](https://keras.io/examples/vision/3D_image_classification/)

Comment: Got it. Could you tell me how to feed Nifti files from folders in case of multi-label classification? Maybe I've missed it, but I've never seen feeding images from a hard drive in case of multi-label classification.

Comment: You didn't give description about your labels. After loading your scans, make sure to load your labels in a way that matches the images. The data in the end should be similar to: 
scan_1.nifti — label 1 — label 2